How to monitor ffplay output and restart the process when it hangs?
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 on which there are 4 terminal windows running, each running a little script holding the following command:
ffplay -left 0 -top 0 -x 960 -y 540 -rtsp_transport tcp "rtsp://user:pass@camera-IP:port/videoSub"

I switched to using -rtsp_transport tcp after having issues without it (see [Why does ffplay show lots of errors in the stream of security cameras?][1] for more details).
The image quality is perfect, but from time to time one or more streams "hang". At the moment, I still have a keyboard and mouse attached to the Raspberry Pi, so I can easily quit the camera window and restart the command in the associated terminal window, but that is a temorary solution.
As long as ffplay is running correctly, it displays lines with which appears a timestamp at the front. This leads me to two questions:

how can I (easily) monitor this output?
how can I, once the monitor notices that the output is halted, kill the ffplay command and restart the command?

I'm a software developer with a Windows background, my initial thought would be to whip something up in C#, and run it on the Pi via Mono. Having said that, I'd like to have a way to do this on the Raspberry Pi via scripting or via Python, in order to avoid both Mono and C#.
How would I best approach this?

Use pyav (Python), there you would catch errors during streaming also you can use an watch thread

@Christoph Am I correct in thinking that I need to stream the video via pyav, as in that I need to write Python code to show the video stream? I'm guessing that would be overkill since that part already works fine... I'm more looking for a way to parse the output of ffplay and go from there. On the other hand, I can't quite judge what pyav can do for me. Would you happen to have an example or an article with some more explanation please? Thanks!
